# Color the cells HTML tables according to their numbers with Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have a set of html tables with numbers in the style like these:

```
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>0:00 - 8:00</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>8:00 - 18:00</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>18:00 - 0:00</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Day</th>
    <th>Time</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>0:00 - 8:00</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>8:00 - 18:00</td>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>18:00 - 0:00</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>60</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

[jsbin.com/evakac/2/edit][1]

I want to color the cells of this table: If there is a low number in one of the cells compared to the other cells in the same column, the color should be green. If it is a high number it should be more intensive color.

I know that there are plugins like jquery datatables (http://www.datatables.net/) out there, but i have not found 
a plugin that is sufficient.

Is there a javascript / javascript plugin that can help me? I prefer jQuery-based solutions.

Update: Here's a plugin that can do that:

http://geertdedeckere.be/shop/graphup/

Does anyone know a solution like this for free?

Comment: 'It should maybe be red'? Be specific as to your criteria, and explain in what way the other plugins are not 'sufficient,' what is it that you want that they don't achieve, or offer?

Comment: Make your question a bit more clear. What is the selection and colouring criteria? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look at http://geertdedeckere.be/shop/graphup/ , but it isn't free.

Comment: this is not bad! But is there another plugin that is available for free?

Comment: @mcknight, take the time to learn jQuery and write the plugin yourself.  Then you can share it with everyone for free.

Comment: @Sparky and we would thus have utopia!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [HeatColor](http://www.jnathanson.com/blog/client/jquery/heatcolor/index.cfm). It should let you do what you want and its free.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you can code this is a very simple way :)

I made an example for you based on 2 steps :

1. investigate the values and calculate greater and lowers values
2. paint the cells based on the result

take a look on the code

```
 var result = new Array();

    // calculate 
    $('#source tr').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        result[id] = new Array();
        result[id]['bigger'] = -1;
        result[id]['smaller'] = 99999999;

        $(this).find('td').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('class') === 'data') {
                var n = Number($(this).text());

                if (n > result[id]['bigger']) {
                    result[id]['bigger'] = n;
                }

                if (n < result[id]['smaller']) {
                    result[id]['smaller'] = n;
                }
            }

        })
    });

    // add some colors
    $('#source tr').each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        $(this).find('td').each(function () {

            if ($(this).attr('class') === 'data') {
                var n = Number($(this).text());

                if (n == result[id]['bigger']) {
                    $(this).css("background", "#CC0000");
                }

                if (n == result[id]['smaller']) {
                    $(this).css("background", "#00CC00");
                }
            }

        })
    });
```

the full example is at http://jsfiddle.net/kSxTA/
this is a very simple implementation with only 2 values, but if you have more values just add more levels, or sort the values and match to a list of predefined colors.